# Custom Headers with GRPC in .NET Core

Tags: grpc, grpc-c#

I am working on building a service in GRPC using .NET core. The scenario is as follows - there are 2 services - A and B.

Service A exposes a REST API.

Service B exposes GRPC API.

User invokes Service A, and Service A invokes Service B. I need to pass the headers sent by the user to Service B.

How can I do this with GRPC? [The Interceptor interface](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.Interceptors.html) does not seem to expose the Metadata collection.

Answer (score 8):

To forward the headers sent from client, on the rest api you can do something like this:

```
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5005");
        
var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

Metadata headers = new()
{
    { "myCustomHeader", myCustomHeader }
};

var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = model.Name }, headers);
```

Using the Metadata you can pass all headers that you need.

On the gRPC service side, you need to use HttpContextAccessor [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

This way you can read the http context request headers

```
string header = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["myCustomHeader"];
```

take a look at this repo: [here](https://github.com/a-pedroso/HttpHeader-Rest-gRPC)